# Y-Axis Issues with barp()

Tags: r, bar-chart, yaxis

I need help understanding why the bars print incorrectly when using `barp()` when I manually set the `ylim` argument.

Essentially, I have a vector of values (for the height argument) that contains only positive numeric values, but I want the barp() y-axis set to a y-axis limit of, say, [-100,500]. When I set a y-limit that that goes from negative to positive, `barp()` creates large bars that start from the very bottom, even though they should only start from the zero line.

I tried replicating the exact bars using the original `barplot()` function and I get exactly what I wanted. However, I prefer using the plotrix's `barp()` function because 1) it produces the zero line x axis (which I do not know how to do on `barplot()`) and 2) `barp()` allows me to plot bars and lines on the same graph while `barplot()` does not align added lines with the bars.

Below, I wrote out some code that produces the issue. The Figure 2 plot is the problematic one I want to call attention to. I want to create an image just like Figure 4, but using `barp()`. If that is not possible, I would settle for using `barplot()` if it were possible to create the x-axis line (where the zero line would be).

I tried reading the documentation but I did not catch anything that would explain this issue. Could someone assist me in identifying why one barplot function works but the other does not?

Thanks!

---

```
library(plotrix)

test.vector.mixed = as.numeric(c(-200,-20,50,170,200,250,200,220,205,230,350))
test.vector.positives = as.numeric(c(200,20,50,170,200,250,200,220,205,230,350))

months.index.abb = month.abb[c(8:12,1:6)]

# this displays correctly
barp(
  test.vector.mixed,
  names.arg = months.index.abb,

  col = ifelse(test.vector.mixed < 0, "red", "#108a4c"),
  main = "Figure 1: barp() test with Negatives",
  ylim = c(-500,400)
)

# this does not display correctly
barp(
  test.vector.positives,
  names.arg = months.index.abb,

  col = ifelse(test.vector.positives < 0, "red", "#108a4c"),
  main = "Figure 2: barp() test with Positives",
  ylim = c(-500,400)
)

# this displays correctly
barplot(
  test.vector.mixed,
  names.arg = months.index.abb,

  col = ifelse(test.vector.mixed < 0, "red", "#108a4c"),
  main = "Figure 3: barplot() test with Negatives",
  ylim = c(-500,400)
)

# this is what I want barp() to do
barplot(
  test.vector.positives,
  names.arg = months.index.abb,

  col = ifelse(test.vector.positives < 0, "red", "#108a4c"),
  main = "Figure 4: barplot() test with positives",
  ylim = c(-500,400)
)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: what does barp do that you can't get from barplot?

Comment: @rawr The minor issue is that in the above image, there is no horizontal line that cuts across where the zero should be (x axis). I am not sure how to produce that line. But of greater concern is that I would have to do some sort of transformation to my data so that a bar plot can align with an overlaid line; I don't quite understand how the transformation works so I would rather not deal with it. See this link here: https://www.r-bloggers.com/adding-lines-or-points-to-an-existing-barplot/

Comment: barp has a weird transformation, but I think barplot is straight-forward `bp <- barplot(test.vector.positives, ylim = c(-500,400)); lines(bp, test.vector.positives); abline(h = 0)`

Comment: @rawr okay, so as long as I define an object to the `barplot()` and then use that object as an argument to my line, the bars and the line should always align? Sounds good. So I guess at this point I am now wondering out of curiosity what is `barp()` doing wrong? Is it an issue with how the package was written?

Comment: not sure but there is definitely some [weird scaling going on](https://github.com/cran/plotrix/blob/master/R/barp.R#L41:L47) and changes if `negy`. I don't know what the motivation for that function is, but Ben is usually floating around here, perhaps he has some insight